# Delphi: EmbeddedWB weird proxy error?

Tags: delphi, proxy, browser

This is my Form1.FormCreate code:

```
    GoodWB:=TEmbeddedWB.Create(Form1);
    TWinControl(GoodWB).Name :='NetPartBmb';
    TWinControl(GoodWB).Parent := Form1;
    GoodWB.SetBounds(0,50,300,300);
    //GoodWB.ProxySettings.SetProxy('','83.137.53.190:8080','<local>');
    //GoodWB.ProxySettings.AutoLoadProxy:=true;
    GoodWB.Navigate('www.google.com');
```

EmbeddedWB performs weirdly. When I try to load a page it throws an error like if I was not online.
But if I uncomment those proxy settings (The proxy 83.137.53.190:8080 is a fully functionating proxy btw) then it works, but with that proxy. It seems like it uses some unknown proxy.
 How can I disable the proxy and work with my own IP?
BTW: This wasn't happening before and I have also been setting proxies with it before but then I have removed all the proxy code parts so I have no idea what is causing this when there are no codes for proxy settings.

Comment: What is TEmbeddedWB? I don't think that's part of the Delphi standard libraries.  Where did you get it from?

Comment: I think it's this http://www.bsalsa.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how `TEmbeddedWB` works, but in `TWebBrowser` you have to pass a full URL to `Navigate()`, not just the hostname by itself:

```
GoodWB.Navigate('http://www.google.com');
```

If you want to connect to an IP address instead of a hostname, you still would need to specify the protocol scheme:

```
GoodWB.Navigate('http://TheIPHere');
```